# Segmentation Fault for using scanf

Tags: segmentation-fault, c11

I am using basic scanf to take integer input while trying to solve a problem in codeforces, but I am getting segfault while getting the input. Where is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
int n,t;

scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&t);
char arr[n];
gets(arr);
int x=0,i;
for (i=0; i<strlen(arr)-1; i++){
if (arr[i]=='B' && arr[i+1]=='G') {arr[i]='G'; arr[i+1]='B'; x++; if (x==t) break;}

}

printf("%s",arr);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please check the return of `scanf`, the results stored in `n` and `t` and **don't use `gets`**. It has been removed from the C standard for good reasons. And also, please format your code before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jens' comment pointed out the cause. Here is a more elaborated answer.

The following code is problematic.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
char arr[n];
gets(arr)
```

If the length of input string read by `gets` is larger than n, then you get out-of-bounds write. It might not be a problem of the input string is always less than n chars. Here is [a live test](https://cee.studio) to demonstrate the problem.

a proposed fix:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
char arr[n];
fgets(arr, n-1, stdin);
arr[n-1] = '\0' //make sure the string is terminated.
```